# Consulta ORACLE

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo el siguiente problema, Necesito generar una consulta para obtener:
Cuantas veces una persona hace una acción.
Sin embargo el problema es: 1 persona puede hacer dicha opción en equipos diferentes. ejemplo

- Persona 1 hace promote en el equipo 1
- Persona 2 hace promote en el equipo 1
- Persona 2 hace promote en el equipo 2.

Al contar y agrupar, me cuenta la veces que hace la accion, pero no me filtra las veces que esa persona hizo la accion en cada equipo.

La pregunta es ¿Como realizo la consulta para que me muestre el nombre de la persona, y las veces que hizo esta accion por equipo?

Consulta:

```html
SELECT nombre as "NAME", Count(equipo) AS "ENVIRONMENTNAME" 
FROM tabla "HI"
INNER JOIN tabla2 "HA" ON HA.id = HI.id
WHERE HI.accion='Promote'
group by nombre
Order by "ENVIRONMENTNAME"  DESC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si traes el nombre, acción, equipo y el conteo, tendrías el resultado que solicitas.
Te dejo la siguiente consulta. O

```
Persona 1 hace promote en el equipo 1
Persona 2 hace promote en el equipo 1
Persona 2 hace promote en el equipo 2
Persona 2 hace promote en el equipo 2

Persona  Acion         Equipo   Cantidad
1       'Promote'        1        1
2       'Promote'        1        1
2       'Promote'        2        2

SELECT HA.nombre as NAME, HI.accion AS ACCION, HI.equipo AS EQUIPO, count(*) AS CANTIDAD
FROM tabla HI
INNER JOIN tabla2 HA ON HA.id = HI.id
WHERE HI.accion='Promote'
group by HA.nombre, HI.accion, HI.equipo
Order by count(*)  DESC;
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciono a la Perfeccion